# How to run awk for some number of lines.?

Tags: linux, awk

i want to extract some lines by awk. is it possible to do the following task:

```
ls -l | awk 'BEGIN FOR(i=122;i<=129;i++) FNR==i'
```

i want to display the details from line number 122 to 129..

Correct me & how i can achieve it.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display lines 122 to 129 (both inclusive), say:

```
command | awk 'NR>=122&&NR<=129'
```

Answer (score 4):

You just have to indicate the NR in a condition like the following:

```
ls -l | awk 'NR>=122 && NR<=129'
```

#### Tests

```
$ cat a
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
$ awk 'NR>=3' a
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
$ awk 'NR>=3 && NR<=8' a
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
ls -l | awk '(FNR >= 122 && FNR <= 129)'
```

Sed:

```
ls -l | sed -ne '122,129p'
```

Example:

```
> for (( I = 1; I <= 200; ++I )); do echo "$I : $RANDOM"; done | sed -ne 122,129p
122 : 26175
123 : 25889
124 : 3005
125 : 13134
126 : 27387
127 : 3307
128 : 21926
129 : 2043
```

Comment: +1 for the sed one, I thought of sed too when I read the question. your example is nice, but `seq 200|sed...` could be simpler. ;)